# GAE java/python logs export not exporting latest logs

Tags: google-app-engine

not sure if Google App Engine changed something, but I was able to download logs until recently to parse the logs for generating custom analytics on usage etc. Now the log is getting exported but the issue is that the last log is from Nov 23 while I see logs as recent as 12/18 in the console. The commandline version I use is as below.

```
appcfg.cmd -n 90 --severity=1 request_logs <appDirPath> <full_log_file_path>
```

Has anything changed recently with logs export with GAE ? Does anyone know a workaround for this issue. If it matters, I am using appengine-java-sdk-1.9.64.

Comment: Looks like no one has any pointers, I upgraded to appengine 1.9.70 and still has same issue of exporting only till Nov 23 2018. The manual workaround I am using now is to click on Download logs on top right side as csv and using that in our modified analytics extractor. If anyone has ideas, please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. Posting here in case anyone else runs into similar silly issue. After upgrading to google-cloud-sdk and Java 8, I am getting the following log in console

```
    Configuration Warning : <application>/<version> XML elements and --application/--version should not be specified when staging

The following parameters will be scrubbed from app.yaml
application : appId
version : chosenVersion
```

Since google app engine was ignoring this, it was creating a new version with dateTimeStamp with new deployment. But the command line in my post points to the  appDirPath that has the appengine-web.xml listing a version and so it was downloading the logs for that version only. Since that version was overridden with a new dynamic version on Nov 24, the command line was giving only logs till Nov 23. It took me a while to figure out so posting for anyone else who run into this issue.